# Python Tkinter storing all images from directory in a vector

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to store all images from folder (there are 46 of them) in one vector so I can easly acces them later, where am I wrong?

It gives me following error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '01_a.jpg'

```py
import tkinter as tk
import os
from PIL import Image

root = tk.Tk()

tkimages = []

def laodImages():
    for image in os.listdir(os.getcwd() + '\chars'):
        if image.endswith("jpg"):
            im = Image.open(image)
            tkimage = tk.PhotoImage(im)
            tkimages.append(tkimage)


laodImages()
print(tkimages[1].name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should append the parent directory path first.

```
import os

import tkinter as tk
import os
from PIL import Image

root = tk.Tk()

tkimages = []
path = os.getcwd() + '/chars'

def laodImages():
    for image in os.listdir(path):
        if image.endswith("jpg"):
            im = Image.open(os.path.join(path, image))
            tkimage = tk.PhotoImage(im)
            tkimages.append(tkimage)
```

Comment: in 'os.listdir(path)' it gives me " Undefinde variable 'p' " of couirse i defined path earlier just as you did

Comment: Also you are escaping  'c' when you write '\chars'. Probably you want to write '/chars'.

Comment: ocne i make it /chars, not \chars it doesnt give any errors, but still cannot print anythiong like tkimages[1] neither i can do `image_label = tk.Label(root,image=tkimages[1])`

Answer (score 0):

So I chsoe other, to me simpler way to do it and it works (btw: I pair image with its name)

```py
import tkinter as tk
import glob
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()


pairs = []
paths = glob.glob('./chars/*.jpg')


for path in paths:
    string1 = path
    name = string1[11:len(string1) - 4]

    tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=path)   

    pair = (tkimage, name)
    pairs.append(pair)
```

I know its not the cleanest way but does the job

Answer (score 0):

**I did this in my project to save images from folder to a list and display it using tkinter**

```
parking_img_list = []

parking_img_path = '/home/stephen/Desktop/Smart Parking System/Smart Parking UI/UI_Layout/*.png'
parking_path_list = glob.glob(parking_img_path)

for parking_file in parking_path_list:
    path = parking_file
    park_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=path)
    parking_img_list.append(park_img)

print(parking_img_list)
image_number = 1


my_display = Label(image=parking_img_list[0])
```